# How to make custom property of Linq2SQL class bindable?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, data-binding

My Database has a Table Foo with the Property IsTrue.
I made a Linq2SQL Class "myData.dbml" for this Database and added the generated Foo-Class to my Datasources bar.
I have a Simple Winforms Window with a ToggleButton which should bind to the inverse of IsTrue.

To achieve this I tried to add the Property NotTrue to the myData.dbml but this caused an SQLException, invalid row name "NotTrue".
I tried to add the Property Code to the myData.cs like this:

```
public bool NotTrue {
    get {
        return !this._IsTrue;
    }
    set {
        if (this._IsTrue == value) {
            this.OnIsTrueChanging(!value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._IsTrue = !value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("IsTrue");
            this.SendPropertyChanged("NotTrue");
            this.OnIsTrueChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

But then the Property didnt appear when adding Foo to Datasources even when adding `[Bindable(true)]`

What worked, was binding to IsTrue and negating the Binding with this:

```
private void InvertBoolBinding(ControlBindingsCollection collection,string property) {
    foreach (Binding b in collection) {
        if (b.PropertyName.Equals(property)) {
            ConvertEventHandler invert = new ConvertEventHandler((sender, e) => { e.Value = !((bool)e.Value); });
            b.Format += invert;
            b.Parse += invert;
        }
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
InvertBoolBinding(lockToggleButton.DataBindings, "IsChecked");
```

Though in my main project there's a huge amount of those Bindings, this approach is quite a hassle. It seems that Datasources isn't able to connect properties through partial classes. When I add the property to the myData.designer.cs, it is found. But this class get regularly regenerated and my property gets lost.

So maybe I need a completely different approach or maybe theres a way to make partial class extensions work.
I hope you got some idea on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Linq2SQL class to a different assembly makes Visual Studio resolve the partial connection.

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133349/bindingsource-doesnt-appear-to-contain-properties-created-in-partial-class).